# activate prettier-js-mode after every save

Tags: js2-mode

I am using [prettier-js-mode](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-emacs) which is great and here is my configuration:

```
(use-package prettier-js
  :commands (prettier-js-mode prettier)
  :init (add-hook 'js2-mode-hook 'prettier-js-mode)
  :bind (:map js2-mode-map ("M-q" . prettier))
  :config
  (setq prettier-target-mode "js2-mode")
  (setq prettier-js-args '(
    "--trailing-comma" "all"
    "--bracket-spacing" "false")))
```

At the moment I have to `M-x` and select `prettier-js` from the meta menu.

How could I run `prettier-js` after a save happens?

Comment: Is the `prettier-js-mode` enabled when you open `js2-mode`? If yes it should work automatically.

Comment: `prettier-js-mode` should run `prettier` on save automatically - it is part of the mode. When you save, check your messages for any errors that may be encountered. Do you have the prettier program installed? (ie: `npm i -g prettier`)